# Android MapView Multiple Random Markers Removal with Double Tap On Marker

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, marker, osmdroid

I have question about marker. Looks like after I created next marker, the onDoubleTap method of the marker is no longer available for PREVIOUS markers (NOT the last marker created). Any suggestion on how to fix it where I want to be able to remove it each markers randomly with double tapping on it via onDoubleTap method? What is causing for PREVIOUS markers to no lose track of onDoubleTap method?  I have notice is I can double tap anywhere in the map and LAST marker disappears.  I want only when doubled tapped ON TOP of that marker it only disappears.  Also, when my map rotates markers disappears.

```
Overlay touchOverlay = new Overlay(this) {
ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay = null;

@Override
protected void draw(Canvas arg0, MapView arg1, boolean arg2) {

}

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e,
 final MapView mapView) {
 Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
 GeoPoint loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(),
 (int) e.getY());
 ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 OverlayItem mapItem = new OverlayItem("", "", new GeoPoint(
 (((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000),
 (((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000)));
 mapItem.setMarker(OfflineMapDemoActivity.this.getResources()
 .getDrawable(R.drawable.location_mark));
 overlayArray.add(mapItem);
 anotherItemizedIconOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
                        getApplicationContext(), overlayArray, null);
 mapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
 mapView.invalidate();
 return true;
 }


@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
//remove marker here
mapView.getOverlays().remove(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
return true;
}
}; //end of Overlay

mapView.getOverlays().add(touchOverlay);
```

Comment: Where do you add the events for your markers?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel I do not add any events to marker... this might bet the issue.  Those two onSingleTapConfirmed and onDoubleTap are mapview events not marker events. How do I add event to markers?

Comment: You can refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882441/how-to-add-a-marker-when-i-touch-the-map-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Your method is far from the expected result. You are sub-classing Overlay, which is really a "poor" class. You will have for instance to implement touch detection yourself.

I suggest the following approach:

- add [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) library.
- start by using Marker, and sub-class it to implement support for onDoubleTap event
- look at Marker.onLongPress source code, to implement your own onDoubleTap method (using hitTest method to check if double tap was on this marker).